# Logic behind prestashop image storage

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to know the logic used in storing images in prestashop and where to get the location link from the database. I know where the images are stored but don't know the logic behind the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the  image id is 104, i.e 104-thickbox_default.jpg,
you  will find  the  image  in the  location  img/p/1/0/4.
The  logic behind the  image id e.g 104  can be found in the table  ps_image.
This table consists of the  product id  with their  respective image id.